# Haskell Data.Vector.Storable.unsafeFromForeignPtr with C struct pointer/array field

Tags: arrays, pointers, haskell, vector, ffi

I'm using the Haskell FFI with a C library that defines a number of `struct` types containing members which are pointers to `double`s, intended to be treated as arrays of `double`s:

```
typedef struct Foo {
  int length;
  double* values;
} FooT;
```

In my Haskell bindings to this library I have an equivalent data type in which I'm trying to use `Data.Vector.Storable.Vector Double` for the array:

```
data Foo = Foo {
  length :: Int,
  values :: Data.Vector.Storable.Vector Double
} deriving (Show, Eq)
```

In order to marshall data between the C library and my Haskell code, of course, I have to write `Storable` instances for these types. I'm trying to work out a way of using `Data.Vector.Storable.unsafeFromForeignPtr` to create Haskell `Vector`s from the `double*` arrays that the C library has allocated and populated on the heap. I'm hoping that by doing this I can avoid copying the contents of the `double*` arrays and just have the `Vector` as a kind of wrapper over the array. (Side question would be: given that the `double*` arrays can be up to 10,000s of `double`s, is it worth pursuing this non-copying?)

This is what I have so far. I'm using `hsc2hs` macros to help generate the `Storable peek` implementation:

```
instance Storable Foo where
  alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: CDouble)
  sizeOf _ = #{size FooT}

  peek ptr = do
    len <- (#peek FooT, length) ptr
    valuesField <- ((#peek FooT, values) ptr) :: IO (ForeignPtr Double)
    let values' = DV.unsafeFromForeignPtr0 valuesField len

    return Foo { length = len, values = values' }

  poke ptr (Foo len values') = do
    (#poke FooT, length) ptr len
    DV.unsafeWith values' (\ptrValues -> (#poke FooT, values) ptr ptrValues)
```

So in my `peek` I'm trying to `#peek` the `values` member as a `ForeignPtr Double` which I could then use with `unsafeFromForeignPtr`. However, `#peek` generates code like this:

```
valuesField <- (((\ hsc_ptr -> peekByteOff hsc_ptr 16)) ptr) :: IO (ForeignPtr Double)
```

and gets stuck because there's no `Storable` instance for `ForeignPtr Double`. I think if I tried to implement an instance for `ForeignPtr Double` I would just be commuting the problem of how to access the address value of a `struct` member to the `peek` implementation for that instance.

So in summary, how can I access an address value (i.e. pointer) `struct` member in such a way that I can use it as an argument to `unsafeFromForeignPtr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about using hsc2hs but you already have a pointer to the data in `peek` so you just use that, with the proper offset of course. Disclaimer: this compiles, but is untested.

```
import Data.Vector.Storable (Vector, unsafeFromForeignPtr)
import Foreign.Storable (Storable (..))
import Foreign.C.Types 
import Foreign.ForeignPtr (newForeignPtr_)
import Foreign.Ptr 

instance Storable Foo where
  peek ptr = do 
    len <- peek (castPtr ptr)
    valsPtr <- newForeignPtr_  (castPtr ptr `plusPtr` (sizeOf (undefined :: CInt)))
    return $ Foo len $ unsafeFromForeignPtr valsPtr 0 len
```

Comment: Looks like `newForeignPtr_` is the important bit here. I couldn't get manual calculation of the `plusPtr` right hand argument to work, but using `newForeignPtr_` with `hsc2hs`'s `#peek` generated pointer works.

Comment: I have composed an answer using this suggestion but I can't post it until later because I'm too n00b and the internet doesn't trust me :-/ Hopefully I'll still be bothered to post it...

Comment: @rjlewis If you want, edit my answer with your solution at the bottom. I should be able to accept the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using user2407038's suggestion of `newForeignPtr_` the working solution to this is:

```
instance Storable Foo where
  alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: CDouble)
  sizeOf _ = #{size FooT}

  peek ptr = do
    len'    <- fmap fromIntegral (((#peek FooT, len) d) :: IO CInt)

    valuesField <- ((#peek FooT, values) ptr) :: IO (Ptr Double)
    valuesPtr   <- newForeignPtr_ valuesField
    let values' = DV.unsafeFromForeignPtr0 valuesField len

    return Foo { length = len, values = values' }
```

I found that just `#peek`ing the `int` field was giving me garbage whereas explicitly declaring it to be `CInt` and then using `fromIntegral` to convert that to an `Int` gives me the right value. And then I actually have a correct length to use with `unsafeFromForeignPtr`. I've then done a similar thing with the `double*` pointer too: explicitly declare it to be `Ptr Double`.

In my actual application some of the `struct`s also have `char*` type field which, similar to the `int` fields, I found were also just coming out as garbage after the `#peek`. Again, explicitly declaring their types to be `CString` solved that too.